# How to increase rhel-root space?

Tags: rhel, partition, root

In my RHEL 7.8 server, I have allocated 100GB for /root. I need more space because I need to install more software that will be available systemwide for all users. I am new to Linux and not very familiar with the system. My questions are:

1. If I want to increase my /rhel-root, what should I do?
2. If I can't increase the space, how can I change the download and software Installation location?
3. For case 2, is there anything else I need to do so my users have access to the installed software?

Thanks a lot for your time!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: shrink your `/home` (you have more than 1 TB free space there) and grow your root logical volume.

```
lvresize -L-500g rhel/root -r
lvresize -L+500g rhel/home -r
```

Note this might not be possible if the home logical volume uses XFS filesystem which is not shrinkable (and XFS is default on RHEL).

Option 2: resize your physical volume (you have 136 GB free space on your hard drive), add it to the `rhel` volume group and grow the `root` logical volume

```
fdisk /dev/sda (resize the /dev/sda3 partition)
pvresize /dev/sda3
lvresize -L+130g root/rhel -r
```

And as always with storage: backup everything important and I recommend doing this offline from a Live image or something similar.

Recommended reading: [Configuring and managing LVM logical volumes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_administration) (RHEL documentation)